# Can we do something 'How do I do X in AngularJS/React/framework Y'?

Tags: discussion

I don't mean this to be a rant; I genuinely want to make this situation as good as it can be, even if that means we're already there and there's no better answer.

I'm seeing more and more questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40306927/find-object-by-its-property-in-array-of-objects-with-angular-way) one. Sometimes they're somewhat more legitimate like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40359531/how-to-iterate-through-an-array-of-objects-in-polymer) one, but most of the time they have easy, *native* solutions that have been beat to death elsewhere. I've been marking as duplicate to have the OP protest "Oh noes, I want the *AngularJS* way to do this", or even worse "I don't want to use JavaScript" (CoffeeScript and jQuery tags being particularly frequent offenders).

Can we get

A) some kind of canonical resource to point these people at with a polite explanation of why this type of question is inherently flawed and

B) a canonical close-as-dupe answer for all questions like this instead of individually tracking down the individual duplicates. Or is that a bad idea?

Bonus points if A & B are the same thing. Or am I off-base with this?

Comment: close as dupe ?

Comment: @KevinL yeah that's what I've been doing, the problem is that it doesn't help the OP get over the hump of understanding that its turtles all the way down, this is still all just JavaScript which is the persistent misunderstanding that I'm trying to get past.

Comment: You'd have to write a long answer that explains what the library devs intended to wrap and what they intentionally did not wrap.  With extra emphasis on the "not wrap" reasoning, you have to convincingly prove that it can't be done the "angular-way".  Your answer is not likely to be appreciated ("that's not what I asked for!") and is a DV magnet.  And it does not age well because they may well decide to wrap in the next version.  You can't win so don't bother, your vote is plenty good enough and does not have to be explained.  We use votes to arrive at the best solution, works here too.

Comment: @HansPassant: In the first example, the requested functionality _is_ available in angular ;-)

Comment: Well, don't tell me, tell the questioner.

Comment: Nothing more needs to be done... either it's a dupe, off topic, unclear/broad, or it's not...

Comment: @KevinB there seems (from the conversation below and the fact that it has been closed and then reopened) to be a lack of consensus about how to deal with these questions in general...or at least this specific one.

Comment: Yes, a lot of people hate the "How do i do X" questions, and others see them as the most useful questions on this site (as long as it's not a dupe/unclear/broad of course). I'm in the latter group.

Answer (score 15):

> I've been marking as duplicate to have the OP protest *"Oh noes, I wan't the angular way to do this"*

I'd argue that that is a perfectly valid reason to protest the closure.
In fact, for that reason I re-opened the first example. It should be closed as a dupe of an angular question, if at all.

I don't want jQuery solutions for my native JavaScript questions, and I don't want JavaScript solutions for my jQuery questions.

It is perfectly reasonably to ask for a solution using a specific library, especially considering said library has built-in support for the requested functionality. It doesn't matter if the feature is also possible without a library.

Comment: Agreed. If a question asks for Y, then only Y is the answer until the OP can be persuaded to change the question to at least include X. No matter how much more sense X makes.

Comment: @Gimby: or _"What you want is Y, but you can also do X"_. As long as you at least answer the OP's question.

Comment: True, although those kind of answers might sneakily side to giving a full explanation of X and leaving Y as a low quality explanation. I'm not a big supporter of unfocussed answers myself, but I wouldn't downvote an answer that does it right.

Comment: @Gimby: agreed. Basically, judge on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: @Cerbrus the problem isn't that the solution is *possible* with the library (if that were the demarcation line then technically *everything* is possible without a library), but that it is *trivial without it*. No one should protest questions asking how to turn 50 LoC into 3 with a library on the grounds that there's a native solution. But in cases like this the framework buys you little if anything at the cost of increasing vendor lock-in and (arguably) decreasing readability for anyone not familiar with the framework.

Comment: @Gimby I don't know that I agree with that, the counter argument is that its just an XY problem.

Comment: @JaredSmith: In this example, The library offers a 1-line solution to filter an HTML input element. Something that's more complicated in native JS

Comment: @Cerbrus "more complicated in native JS"? Its one line of (readable) code: `var item73 = myArray.filter(i => i.id === '73')[0]`, copied straight from the other answer to that question.

Comment: @JaredSmith: Now apply that to a HTML element. You can't beat `{{ myArray | filter : {'id':73} }}` with native JS.

Comment: @Cerbrus and the other version won't work on HTMLElements because...reasons?

Comment: @JaredSmith It's not a matter of simplicity, readability or length, I believe. The question is how do I do it with Angular. That's it. You may find that looking for an Angular solution while there is a good enough native alternative is illogical but that, in no way, makes the question a duplicate. You can downvote thinking it is not useful, leave a comment explaining that but cannot close the question because you think it's illogical.

Comment: @JaredSmith: The point is that the OP is looking for an Angular solution, probably because he's using Angular already. In that case, it's ridiculous to use native JS for data binding.

Answer (score 4):

Schematically, the new question (which I will refer to as #1) is:

> How can I do X with Angular?

... and your dupe target (#2) is:

> How can I do X with plain JavaScript?

Now, suppose the new question was instead (#3):

> How can I do X with Angular? I know it is easier to do X with plain JavaScript, but I am curious anyway.

#3, however, is clearly not a duplicate of #2. Since a comment by the OP which is strictly about their motives does not affect the subject matter of the question, that makes it evident #1 is not a duplicate of #2 either.

It also helps to consider what should happen if "do[ing] X with Angular" was somehow dangerous, or outright impossible. In such cases, closing the question as a duplicate of a plain JavaScript solution would not be a reasonable resolution. Rather, it would be expected that the danger or impossibility would be explained through answers. These answers, then, might cover better approaches, and possibly link to questions about them. Now, the concrete situation we are talking about is quite similar to the hypothetical scenarios we are talking about. The main difference is that, in your case, there are no clear red flags to be raised against the Angular solution. That being so, your suggestion of a plain JavaScript solution would perhaps be more appropriately done through a comment rather than an answer, though that is ultimately a judgment call. In any case, the question should not be closed as a duplicate.

Answer (score -2):

After mulling over the feedback received here I think it boils down to the following:

1) The point of closing duplicates is to prevent cluttering the site by scattering the same information about randomly, its a DRY thing.

2) Asking how to do something in framework x that has a trivial native solution does not necessarily make it a duplicate.

I personally think point 2 above is almost always wrong: if the underlying problem is how to filter a list and a Q/A on that already exists then problem solved. *However*, I know think it somewhat presumptuous to err on the side of closure: my opinion on the subject is not binding, and the community seems to feel otherwise based on the feedback here.