# Can I flag Android questions for Kotlin, which have answers in Java, as duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, vote-to-close

I can see a lot of Android questions written in Kotlin which already have answers in other question with Java. Android Studio provides a code-converter to convert Java to Kotlin.

Should I flag these questions as duplicate?

Comment: We have similar discussions caused by Apple's transition from Objective-C to Swift: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289230/4751173

Comment: Depends. If code is simple then you might. Otherwise I would not because translating from one language (even with converters) is not always trivial nor such results are the best possible options for given language. On the other hand, if the question itself is poor, then closing it as such duplicate is good option.

Comment: If the question is poor then it shouldn't be closed as a duplicate, it should be closed for which ever reason makes it poor.

Comment: Either way, a link is probably appropriate. I've been known to leave links in comments, with the text *Related (not quite duplicate)*.

Comment: @AshleyMedway I forgot to add if you can dupehammer it and close it faster. Otherwise, yes, it is better to close poor questions for reasons that make them poor.

Comment: Given the response I got to [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/337229/can-we-do-something-how-do-i-do-x-in-angularjs-react-framework-y), I would say the consensus is that it even framework vs. non-framework in the same language are not dupes, much less entirely different languages.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

Please do not do this. It's confusing for people who do not have a full understanding of both languages.

If someone is looking for a generic answer about a concept shared between both languages (e.g., Android layouts) and it is tagged as such (e.g., [android-layouts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/android-layouts) but not [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) or [kotlin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/kotlin)), then sure: flag it as a duplicate. But if someone is learning or using Kotlin for Android and wants an answer in Kotlin that directly addresses the question, then a Java answer may very well be useless.

Say I want to make an Android application in Java. I have an intermediate understanding of Java, but absolutely no knowledge about Kotlin. If I asked a question for Android Java, having it flagged as a duplicate of an Android Kotlin question would be frustrating because I want to know the specifics for Java, not a related JVM language with different idioms.

Comment: [edit to make myself clearer] I'm voting for this. However, as a Kotlin learner, who started with very weak Java knowledge (ok, I still do), if anything I'd prefer the duplicate to link to the Java answer ***iff** that answer translates easily when pasted into Android Studio.*