# Closing TypeScript questions as dupes of JavaScript questions

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

It is equally applicable to any language that is a superset of another language...

Is it reasonable to close a question [tagged as TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/typescript) in favour of a question that asks the same for JavaScript only? Is it reasonable to expect the OP to "fill-in-the-blanks" w.r.t. type annotations, for instance?

Comment: Yes, it is. If the question is not *specific* to the superset language itself, if it is answered already, it is a duplicate.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72185133/11407695) is the question in discussion. Being an SME in both TS and JS I, too, do not see any reason why *would not* it be a duplicate and invite others to evaluate.

Comment: Judge case by case. Always judge case by case. There are no cookie cutter rules to this, it is only a "maybe". In this particular case I would accept "usually" though, but that might not be the case for another superset case.

Comment: 'Is it reasonable to expect the OP to "fill-in-the-blanks"' Isn't this generally how duplicates work? No practical question is a 100% match to another.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi I can put it differently: there is no reason to deviate from the generic ruling about closing as a dupe. If an existing answer is the answer to the question asked, duplicate closure is the right choice. "But what if the author does not understand the answer?". Then they have work to do.

Comment: There are similar Meta discussions regarding [Kotlin -> Java](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/361168/can-i-flag-android-questions-for-kotlin-which-have-answers-in-java-as-duplicat) and [Swift -> Objective-C](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289230/why-do-swift-questions-on-stack-overflow-get-marked-as-duplicates-of-objective-c). Those answers there might apply to this discussion here as well.

Answer (score 13):

> Is it reasonable to close a question tagged as TypeScript in favour of a question that asks the same for JavaScript only?

**Yes, it is.**

Provided the question does not ask about something that is *specific* to the superset language (especially so closely tied together as JavaScript and TypeScript) and has *the same* solution, a question *tagged* with a superset language tag is a duplicate of the question that is a subset of it. I'd go one step further and say that the superset tag does not belong, and the question should also be *retagged*.

> Is it reasonable to expect the OP to "fill-in-the-blanks"

**Yes, it is.**

Do not forget that we are not a code writing service, a help desk, or a forum. We are a knowledge repository — if the author has trouble applying the solution to their *specific* circumstance, it has no bearing on the duplicate status. Note that this does not preclude you from giving a helping hand to the user if you want to: engage with them and explain how to do that.

Comment: What if there's a better answer for the superset language?  It seems that closing it as a duplicate of the subset language would prevent that answer from being posted (which the duplicate voters may not have perfect knowledge of).

Comment: Depends on what you call "better", @RyanM. If that is a hypothetical answer that is the same at its core but is just written better, no, I'd call it not a reason enough to keep it open. If that answer is at its core could suggest something specific to the superset language, then yes, it could be kept open. However, this is not the case for the question in discussion - the answer is the same in both superset and subset language.

Comment: @RyanM I'm not sure that situation applies here since OP included [tag:javascript] in the question from the get-go. They seem to know the differences between TS and JS based on the commentary here and there, so we have to assume they are using JS or will accept answers written in JS... thus a JS-tagged question can be used as a duplicate target.

Comment: @TylerH I'm not sure what you're referring to; there doesn't appear to be a specific question that this is about.